# Simple probability equations for a value appearing within a range

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have basic knowledge in probability theory, although, I'm unsure of the necessary equation and concept to use towards my current idea, and would really appreciate some experienced support towards this.

Firstly, I have count data that is the response, this count data falls within 10 ranges, these ranges are: 0-0.1, 0.1-0.2, 0.2-0.3, 0.3-0.4, 0.4-0.5, 0.5-0.6, 0.6-0.7, 0.7-0.8, 0.8-0.9, and 0.9-1.

The ranges represent the probability of a bird being encountered. For example, if 5 observations are made, and all 5 observations fall within the category of 0-0.1 chance of encountering, whats the probability the 6th will fall within this or any other category? and so forth. Does the assumption of the next bird encounter depend on the amount of evidence acquired, i.e. more observations?

The bird is encountered based on a presence/absence basis. This would have to take into account misidentification, so an error bound by each probable measure of encountering this bird.

An example of how the observations for the bird are made, could be [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/574392v1.supplementary-material?versioned=true) in Appendix 2.

I want to know if there is a probability test to find out from a scale of 0 - 1, the odds of my data falling into either one of these ranges, and the probability of the next unit observations beyond my total observations of falling within any one category.

Say for example, I have within the 10 ranges, a sample count of 10,000. For the first range, we have 3000 counts, the second we have 1500, third 1500, and the remaining 5000 is evenly distributed amongst the last 7 ranges. What's the estimate or even the likelihood of the next sample, beyond the 10,000 of entering one of those groups, based on the evidence of the distribution of the 10,000?

It would be rephrased likeso: -"What are the odds that the probability of the next encounter is 0-0.1 or 0.1-0.2 etc.".

Perhaps a conditional probability model may help me achieve what I'm after, or maybe not?

Comment: I don't get it, you seem to have everything you need it. If there are 3000 observations in the first range, and 10000 observations in total, then the probability of any given observation being in the first range is 3000/10000=0.3 or 30 %, assuming independent observations.

Comment: @user2974951 I see, that would be very helpful! Although, this estimate only relies on the given information of there being a sample space of X observations, with Y of those observations distributed into groups. Then their percentage relevance, based on the distributed size, relative to the entire sample size. Although, what's the estimate or even the likelihood of the next sample, beyond the 10,000 of entering one of those groups, based on the evidence of the distribution of the 10,000?

Comment: This question is really hard to understand for me. I think it would be helpful if you explain a bit more where the bird encounter probability comes from. Is it really that? Or was a bird encountered? And then maybe it's possible to ask your question sticking with bird observations instead of switching to the urn metaphor.

Comment: @Gijs Checkout my updated post.

Comment: `what's the estimate of the next sample, beyond the 10,000 of entering one of those groups, based on the evidence of the distribution of the 10,000` or put differently, what is the probability that the next observation will fall in the first range? If that is your question, it is exactly the probability that you calculated from your sample, 0.3 - again, assuming the observations are independent. But maybe you want to fit a (theoretical) distribution to your sample and then determine the probabilities from it, but that is a different question.

Comment: Meilton I think you are making things complicated by talking about the probability of the probability of a bird encounter. You're going to need some more straightforward model for the bird population I think. What are your observations, what are the rows in your data? If the rows are a visit, then you can score whether or not a bird was seen right? Or how many? Where does the probability range within a visit come from?

Comment: @Gijs You make good points! My dataset has for columns: 1. Landcover, 2. States, 3. Encounter Rates, 4. Habitat changes. The encounter rates were calculated using a random forest model on presence/absence data. However, I placed this data within 10 ranges from 0-10, and took the counts of values falling within the range. Hence, my question towards calculating the next probability of one of these values falling under these ranges. Of course this should take into account effort variables, and covariates, however these have been settled in the RF model. My aim is to gather percentage probability